# Pokemon go saying there's no internet connectivity while i'm on data

Tags: pokemon-go

Pokemon go doesn't work when I'm not connected to wifi even when I'm using mobile data. It still says that there is no internet connectivity. Is there any way to fix this? I have a new phone (iphone) with unlimited data that I got yesterday, perhaps there is something I need to change or set up in settings? Or is it just a game problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does your internet browser work while on mobile data?

Comment: Try toggling airplane mode, or your data, or your wifi, or changing the type of data you use, etc... there are many possible causes and workarounds/fixes, smartphones are finicky things.

Comment: The problem has been resolved, it was an issue with AT&T.

Comment: I have the same issue and yes the browser works on 3G but not PokeGo login with Google account. I have to login via Wifi and then works fine in 3G until the game crashes and then to Wifi to re-login. It's frustrating as hell. I have tried rebooting phone, re-installing app, clearing cache, nothing works. I read somewhere that it may be related to Google Account Security settings. I have fiddled with everything to no avail. Help!